# Remove attribute from layered navigtaion for one category?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, layered-navigation

I'm trying to remove/hide the **price** attribute from layered navigation for a certain category which has all configurable products. Reason is because the price attribute is only considering the config.'s associated products price but not the price of the config. product itself.

How can I remove the price attribute in layered navigation for just one category?

Answer (score 1):

There are not exiting function which remove price filter from one category.

There are need some little hacky code for this case at

**app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTEMPLATE>template>catalog/layer/view.phtml**

```
  <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()):?>
  <?php $show=1;?>
    <!-- curern filter price and currentc Cat match -->
  <?php if($_filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar()!=='price'){?>
    <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category') &&(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()==$catId)):
    $show=0;
        endif;
     ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- check show 
  <?php if($show==1){?>
  <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php endif;?>
```